# Why does overwriting a whole array within a function not replace it, but overwriting element by element does?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am learning javascript. One of the exercises is to write a function that     **overwrites** the values in an array passed in as a parameter. My solution worked within the function, but it did not seem to be passed back from the function. Also if I do the same thing that is not in a function, it also works. After I worked out what the problem was I wrote simplified versions of my solution vs a version that works. But I still don't understand why one works and one doesn't. Is someone able to explain?

Thanks

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(ary){                                
  // This version is successful                                   
  ary[0] = 5;                                                     
  ary[1] = 4;                                                     
  ary[2] = 3;                                                     
  ary[3] = 2;                                                     
  ary[4] = 1;                                                     
  console.log("Within reverseArrayInPlace: " + ary);              
  return ary;                                                     
  }                                                               

function reverseArrayInPlace2(ary){                               
  // This version is not successful                               
  ary = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];                                          
  console.log("Within reverseArrayInPlace2: " + ary);             
  return ary;                                                     
}                                                                 

var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];                                 
reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);                                  
console.log("After reverseArrayInPlace: " + arrayValue);          

var arrayValue2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];                                
reverseArrayInPlace2(arrayValue2);                                
console.log("After reverseArrayInPlace2 - why is order wrong?: " + arrayValue2);

// But this works.
arrayValue2 = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1];                                    
console.log("After outer replace of arrayValue2: " + arrayValue2);
```

### Results:

Within reverseArrayInPlace: 5,4,3,2,1

After reverseArrayInPlace: 5,4,3,2,1

Within reverseArrayInPlace2: 5,4,3,2,1

After reverseArrayInPlace2 - why is order wrong?: 1,2,3,4,5

After outer replace of arrayValue2: 5,4,3,2,1

Comment: When logging an array or any object with `console.log`, use `.slice()` after the array name to make a _copy_ of that array. Otherwise, `console.log` takes the reference of the array and displays a potentially older version of it. The console doesn’t update a modified array automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is a pass-by-value (or call-by-value, if you prefer) language. Assigning a new value to a function parameter inside the function has no effect on the outside world. However, using a passed-in reference to an object to modify property values *does* affect the outside world. You pass in a reference to the array, and then the function can use that reference to stuff new values into the elements of the array.

Your function returns the modified array, but your calling environment ignores that. Change your test:

```
var arrayValue2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];                                
arrayValue2 = reverseArrayInPlace2(arrayValue2);                                
console.log("After reverseArrayInPlace2 - why is order wrong?: " + arrayValue2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, how does that differ from the first one?                                                  `code` var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];                                 
    reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);                                  
    console.log("After reverseArrayInPlace: " + arrayValue);

Comment: @Tarnz In the second one, `ary = [ ... ];` assigns a brand new array to the variable `ary`. That variable is **local** to the function. When you call the function, it gets a **copy** of the reference to the "real" array in the calling context. Assigning a new value to that local variable does not affect the `arrayValue2` variable at all.

Comment: Hhhmmm that's interesting. The book I'm learning out of said that, that would only be the case if I had:   `code` var ary = ... rather than `code` ary = ..., that is it is the "var" keyword that would cause that behaviour.

Comment: @Tarnz in this case `ary` was a parameter in the function declaration - for the most part, that makes it work exactly the same as a local variable declared with `var`. Function parameters are like `var` variables that get assigned a value as an implicit side-effect of the function call.

Answer (score 1):

You're not saving the results.

Do this instead:

```
var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];                                 
arrayValue = reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue);                                  
console.log("After reverseArrayInPlace: " + arrayValue);          

var arrayValue2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];                                
arrayValue2 = reverseArrayInPlace2(arrayValue2);                                
console.log("After reverseArrayInPlace2 - why is order wrong?: " + arrayValue2);
```

or

```
var arrayValue = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];                                                            
console.log("After reverseArrayInPlace: " + reverseArrayInPlace(arrayValue));          

var arrayValue2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];                                
console.log("After reverseArrayInPlace2 - why is order wrong?: " + reverseArrayInPlace2(arrayValue2));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can see why your answers will work. But I'm still not clear why my first function works already as I had it, but I would need to write the call to my second function for it to work, when it is only the content of the function that differs, not how it is called. Thanks